# Git. Update divided files

Tags: git, refactoring

short description about the situation:
I divided one file into smaller files, at the same time someone make own commit  modifying file that I just divided. Now I want connect/update my code with his but I can't. When I make for example `git pull`, git recreates file that I divided.
Is there any way to do that, keeping the order?
Thanks for any reply.

Comment: You didn't get a merge conflict when you pulled?

Comment: I have conflict. Something like that  "git conflict - file deleted in HEAD and modified in revision."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you originally had `file`, and now you have `file-A` and `file-B`

Handling of `file-A` would be easier if git saw this as "`file` moved to `file-A` and then some lines were deleted", but presumably git doesn't see enough similarity so it just says "`file` was deleted; `file-A` was created".

Likewise, handling of `file-B` would be better if git swa it as "`file` moved to `file-B` and then some lines were deleted".

Convincing git to see *both* changes in the "right" way is not so simple, so instead we can just hold its hand through the merge process.

One way or another, merge should report a conflict.  (If it didn't - and instead just quietly commit a bad merge - then undo the merge and restart it with the `--no-commit` option:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
git merge --no-commit
```

This will put you in a "conflict-like" state where you can edit the merge.)

What you need now are four files:

- `file-A` as you committed it
- `file-B` as you committed it
- `file` as it looked before your coworker edited it
- `file` as it looked *after* your coworker edited it

The first two you might already have, but if there's any doubt

```
git checkout HEAD -- file-A file-B
```

The "pre-edit" `file` is the hardest one, because you have to locate a commit that had it.  There are "simpler" options if you know an expression (like maybe `HEAD^`) that points to the right commit, but the most general solution is probably

```
git checkout `git merge-base HEAD origin/master` -- file
```

(Note those are back-ticks.)  You then move it to a new filename

```
mv file base
```

so that you can grab the "post-edit" version of `file`

```
git checkout origin/master file
```

Now you have all the pieces, so you can

```
git merge-file file-1 base file
git merge-file file-2 base file
```

So here we're telling git exactly what our file-by-file merge expectations are.  Each of these could create merge conflicts, but hopefully they will be sensible and easier to resolve than what you're looking at now.

Once you have `file-A` and `file-B` looking good:

```
rm file base
git add .
```

Verify your index state.  (I expect the `git add .` to drop `file` back out of the index, but if for some reason it doesn't you can `git rm --cached -- file`.)

And now you can commit the finished merge.  Be aware that a merge like this one (where manual intervention was required) is the sort of thing that would wreak havoc if you later tried to do a `rebase --preserve-merges` that includes it.  (Any merge wreaks havoc on `rebase` without the `--preserve-merges` option.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to sync your work with your colleague. For example, you can do your changes in a separate branch and then merge it to your current branch. then, you ask him to pull the changes and fix the merge conflicts.

Comment: There's no need to create a branch, etc. etc.  From the description in the question, the two versions are already present and git is already trying to merge them.  (And, based on comments, correctly reporting a conflict even.)  There *are* steps that can be taken that might make it go more smoothly, but branching and merging will just lead to the same situation as current.